# Binding sub-properties with Google Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to bind sub-properties automatically with Google Polymer? Something like AngularJS.

Here is a small example:

This is the element that contains the property **prop1** and updates it after 2sec:

```
<dom-module is="test-elem">

    <script>
        TestElem = Polymer({
            is: "test-elem",

            properties: {
                prop1: { type: String, value: "original value", notify: true }
            },

            factoryImpl: function() {
                var that = this;

                setTimeout(function(){
                    that.prop1 = "new value";
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

And this is the main page, which creates an element and show **prop1** in the dom:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="main-page">

    <span>{{test.prop1}}</span>

</template>

<script>
    var scope = document.getElementById('main-page');

    var t = new TestElem();

    scope.test = t;

</script>
```

Unfortunately, the page doesn't update with the new value.
Is there a way to bind this automatically?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkqt00a7/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found was to add an event handler:

```
t.addEventListener('prop1-changed', function(e){
        scope.notifyPath('test.prop1', e.currentTarget.prop1)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83hjzoc3/

But it's not automatic like AngularJS.

Comment: Guess it's for performance reasons. "As we avoid more sophisticated observation mechanisms such as Object.observe or dirty-checking in order to achieve the best startup and runtime performance cross-platform for the most common use cases, changing an object’s sub-properties directly requires cooperation from the user." https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why, but switching your example from setTimeout to this.async makes it work.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? Because it doesn't seem to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xftbjxn7/

Comment: You are not using the async function correctly, sorry. http://polymer.github.io/polymer/

Answer (score 0):

Binding it as a sub property of the page scope doesn't work automatically because you need to manually call notifyPath('test.prop1', value) on the binding scope. One way to do that is to pass the binding scope to the TestElem constructor. Note that you don't need to worry about that if you bind to a parent element automatically. In that latter case the update is automatic.

The following works and shows two binding, and update, methods. One is automatic, the other requires a notifyPath call on the binding scope passed to the constructor.

```
  TestElem = Polymer({
    is: "test-elem",

    properties: {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: "original value",
        notify: true
      }
    },

    ready: function() {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        that.prop1 = "new value (via ready)";
      }, 2000);
    },

    factoryImpl: function (app) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        app.notifyPath('test.prop1', 'new value (via app scope)');
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
```

.. then reference the element one of two ways:

```
  <test-elem prop1="{{prop1value}}">{{prop1value}}</test-elem>
  <div>{{test.prop1}}</div>
  <script>
    app.test = new TestElem(app);
  </script>
```

Where "app" is the main page's global binding scope (e.g. a  as the a top level element in index.html, as is done in the polymer starter kit demo application).

After two seconds both properties update and the automatically updated html appears follows:

```
new value (via ready)
new value (via app scope)
```

Comment: test-elem.prop1 will only show in main-page initially, main-page will not update on subsequent test-elem.prop1 changes

Comment: You'll have to call notifyPath on subsequent updates.